# C array manipulation in function

Tags: arrays, c, function, methods

In this code i want to user to input numbers in the function then print the array in the main method, but when i try to print in the main method it gives me random numbers.

for eg:
1 2 3
gives
1 3 1895586112

```
void arrayInput(int *arr) {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    printf("enter 3 numbers =");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x,&y,&z);
    arr[0]=x;
    arr[1]=y;
    arr[2]=z;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int *arr[3];
    arrayInput(&arr);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)  
    {  
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);  
    } 
}
```

I want to change the array values without changing the method or param type

Comment: `int *arr[3];` -> `int arr[3];`

Comment: Just pay attention to your compiler. The code you have posted isn't valid C and the compiler told you as much. If you are a beginner and using gcc then compile with something like `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int *arr[3]` is an array of pointers to `int`. But you want an array of `int`.

Simply change:

```
int *arr[3];
arrayInput(&arr);
```

to

```
int arr[3];
arrayInput(arr);
```

This should be covered in your C text book.

**Bonus:**

You can remplace this convoluted code:

```
void arrayInput(int *arr) {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    printf("enter 3 numbers =");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x,&y,&z);
    arr[0]=x;
    arr[1]=y;
    arr[2]=z;
}
```

with this:

```
void arrayInput(int *arr) {
    printf("enter 3 numbers =");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &arr[0],&arr[1], &arr[2]); 
}
```

Comment: Better `int arrayInput(int *arr) { ... return scanf("%d %d %d", &arr[0],&arr[1], &arr[2]) == 3; }`

Comment: @0___________ `scanf` isn't fit for user input anyway, but using it without error checks for toy programs is OK IMO.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work perfectly. Also the bonus was helpful too :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code.
First you have declared `int *arr[3];` which would mean pointer arrays. For your task a simple array is needed. The array variable contains the address of the first element, so you don't need `&`.
A simple corrected code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrayInput(int arr[]) {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    printf("enter 3 numbers =");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x,&y,&z);
    arr[0]=x;
    arr[1]=y;
    arr[2]=z;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int arr[3];
    arrayInput(arr);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)  
    {  
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);  
    } 
}
```

Comment: "which would mean pointer to arrays" NO it means an *array of 3 pointers to* `int`. A *pointer to array of* `int[3]` would be `int (*arr)[3];` Much much different. An *array of pointers* is just that, an array where the elements are pointers. A *pointer to array* is a single-pointer to an array type. (but I knew what you meant and your code correction is correct, but the language may leave the OP with the wrong impression of what a *pointer to array* is)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I had a 'to' as mistake.

Comment: Much better. Not like I've never had a stray `"to"` or other misnomer in my answers `:)`